# Python OpenCV Camera Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

For some reason, I cannot read camera video data using OpenCV and Python 3.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    _, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\To\File\VideoTest.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.3.1\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:339: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

The computer is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and has one USB webcam permanently in use in addition to the new one I am trying to read data from. I have tried changing the line `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` and had an identical error.

I tried replicating the error on my laptop using the same code and USB webcam, but it worked perfectly and I was able to stream the video.

**EDIT**

To debug, I ran the following program line-by-line in the Python shell.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.read())
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
print(cap.read())
```

The code outputted `(False, None)` twice.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what the line `cap.read()` returns in your case.

Comment: @AttoAllas quite certainly `false,None`, since that's the assert you get from `imshow` in this scenario (which happens almost daily on SO).

Comment: @DanMašek I am aware, but I was just checking to make sure that nothing else had fallen through the cracks

Comment: "one USB webcam permanently in use" -- what's using it? What if you stop it?

Comment: The computer is serving a website with live video feed from that first USB webcam. I don't know how to restart the camera feed if I stop it, so I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: @AttoAllas how would I find out what cap.read() returns? Do I do `print(cap.read())` or something else?

Comment: Yes you would. Can you also check whether `cap` actually works by running your code one line by one in the python shell?

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and edit with the new info. Thanks for the assistance.